# How to execute only one test of a feature file?

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have a file with N>10 tests defined in BDD in a feature file.

For debugging purposes, I need to execute only one of the tests many times, but I am not finding any other way than commenting out the other tests.
I am trying now to use the `@focus` tag in front of the test, in a way that cypress IDE actually marks the rest of the tests as `sync skip; aborting execution`, but the test that I need to run actually says `No commands were issued in this test.`.

This is the example .feature file I'm playing with:

```
@e2eTests
@cases
Feature: Test feature

 Scenario: Test 1
   Given foo
   When bar
   Then foobar

@focus
 Scenario: Test 2
   Given bar
   When foo
   Then barfoo!
```

And when running `npm run cypress` and selecting this feature, I get:
[image: cypressIDE]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Try putting `it.only` at the beginning of the test case instead of `it` and run in normally.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [cypress-grep](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-grep) if you are looking for a flaky test, that needs repeating n times.

After installation and configuration (see here: [Burning Tests with cypress-grep](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/burning-tests/)) in terminal indicate which test needs to be repeated and how many times (cypress 7.6) ->

```
npx cypress run --spec cypress/folder/with/test/testFile.spec.ts, --env grep="name/description of specific test", burn= >>numberOfIterations<<
```

Example:

```
npx cypress run --spec cypress/integration/testExample.spec.ts, --env grep="A popup should appear after login",burn=250
```